# Can I set an index-wide description for my indices in Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I am currently experimenting with different settings and/or mappings to organize my indices better in Elasticsearch. One idea I have is to possibly add a description for every index based on its content.

But is there a way to add such a description for a whole index?
I only see a `meta` field for documents; not for indices.

Anyone got any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`_meta` field available in mappings](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-meta-field.html)

```
PUT my-index
{
  "mappings": {
    "_meta": { 
      "description": "Blablabla"
    }
  }
}
```

If you need to modify the metadata after the index has been created, you can do so like this:

```
PUT my-index/_mapping
{
  "_meta": { 
    "description": "Blablabla"
  }
}
```

Comment: Isn't this the way to set meta data for ALL documents within the index?
E.g. every document will have a `_meta.description` field slapped onto them; NOT 1 entry for the whole index.

Comment: No, it's just a way to describe the mapping, and hence, the index that mapping belongs to. It's easy to test ;-)

Comment: It works! Just tested and confirmed :)
I am not sure why I doubted your answer at first... maybe because I still felt like this would do the same thing as `_meta` field for documents :P

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Also note that the [`meta`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/8.7/mapping-field-meta.html) field you're referring to is not per document, but per field

Comment: You are correct! My flaws as a beginner are being exposed :P One more thing; do you know if it's possible to add this index-wide `_meta.description` AFTER the index is created?
I just tried with a simple `PUT` request, but got an error..

Comment: No problem, we're all here to learn ;-) I've updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: Beautiful! Thank you so much for all the info! Much appreciated!

Comment: My pleasure, feel free to ask if you have other questions ;-)